# How to avoid "! LaTeX Error: Environment axis undefined" when using include_tikz with pgfplots?

Tags: r, latex, tikz, r-exams, pgfplots

I have successfully included in an R/exams `.Rmd` file several graphics made in TikZ. The same does not happen when I try to include a plot under `pgfplots` using `include_tikz()`. Whenever `\begin {axis}` and `\end {axis}` are included, beware of the error "! LaTeX Error: Environment axis undefined".

In the RStudio console the legend appears: "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format = pdflatex) restricted \ write18 enabled.entering extended mode", even having enabled in TexStudio write-18. None of these messages appear when I include other TikZ graphs other than `pgfplots`.

Any TikZ graph works when run in TexMaker or TexStudio, which indicates that it is not a problem of the absence of LaTeX libraries or packages.

I include a part of my code, adapted from https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1HCT:

````
```{r datos1, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}

library(exams)
typ <- match_exams_device()

image01<-'
         \\begin{tikzpicture}
         \\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
         \\addlegendimage{empty legend}
         \\addplot {sqrt(x)}; 
         \\addplot {ln(x)}; 
         \\addlegendentry{\\hspace{-.6cm}\\textbf{A title}}
         \\addlegendentry{$\\sqrt{x}$}
         \\addlegendentry{$\\ln{x}$}
         \\end{axis}
         \\end{tikzpicture}
         '
```

```{r grafica01, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(image01, name = "grafiko1", markup = 
"markdown",format = typ,library = c("arrows"),packages = 
"booktabs",width = "7cm",header = "\\usepackage{/home/r- 
exams/Documentos/NuevoRStudio/Rmarkdowns/
Esqueleto/exercises/schoice/ 
LaboratorioTikZ/3dplot}")
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right there in your question title. You need to include the `pgfplots` package:

```
include_tikz(image01, packages = "pgfplots", ...)
```

The other `packages`, `library`, and `header` arguments from the call in your question are not needed.

The reason is that for `include_tikz()` you just use the `{tikzpicture}` code while in the full .tex file that you linked you additionally have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note the `\usepackge{pgfplots}` in the second line!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is a similar process followed to use `Pstricks`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `tex2image()` directly for graphics based on LaTeX code. This is also what `include_tikz()` does internally - just with a couple of convenience features for TikX graphics.

Comment: In this way?:    ```{r grafica01, warning=FALSE,echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
include_tikz(image01, name = "grafiko1", markup = "tex",
format = typ,library = c("calc","3d","shapes.geometric"),
packages = c("pstricks"),width = "5cm")
```